Using constant in param with python
I tried a snippet of code from the holoviz param example as follows:
class PythagoreanTheorem(param.Parameterized):
    a = param.Number(default=0, bounds=(0, None), doc="Length of side a")
    b = param.Number(default=0, bounds=(0, None), doc="Length of side b")
    c = param.Number(default=0, bounds=(0, None), doc="Length of hypotenuse c", constant=True)

    def __init__(self, **param):
        super().__init__(**param) #sets values a and b if provided

        self._update_hypotenuse() #set the value c

    @param.depends("a", "b", watch=True)
    def _update_hypotenuse(self):
        with param.edit_constant(self):
            self.c = math.sqrt(self.a**2+self.b**2)

I can now:
pyjc = PythagoreanTheorem(a=3, b=4)
pyjc.c

This gives the correct value of c.
However, since c is declared with constant=True, I was expecting that the following would fail:
pyjc.c = 10

But it allows for c to be set. This seems wrong. Not sure what is going on here?
I see that the param_edit_constant overrides. But clearly this is needed else c cannot be computed.
